# Prove that the map $\pi$ is a submersion

Tags: manifolds, differential

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $\tilde M$ be the set of real matrices $3 \times 2$ of rank 2.
>
> $$ (u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}
> u_1 & v_1 \\
> u_2 & v_2 \\
> u_3 & v_3
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> and $M$ the set of the vectorial planes of $\mathbb{R}^3$
>
> Give a differentiable structure to $M$   to make the map $\pi: \tilde M \to M$ which sends $(u,v)$ to $L(u,v)$ a submersion.

I have no idea of what chart I have to choose. I have already proven that $\tilde M \subset \mathbb{R}^6$ is an open set so I just have to find a suitable atlas for $M$, calculate the differential $\pi_*$ (computing the derivatives with respect to the $u_i$ and $v_i$) and check that it is surjective.

What charts should I choose? I don't know how to find a suitable atlas for $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any plane in $\mathbb R^3$ determines an orthogonal line. This gives a bijection between $M$ and $\mathbb {RP}^2$, the projective plane. The atlas on $M$ is determined by this map and the atlas on the projective plane.

A good resource for the smooth structure on $\mathbb {RP}^2$ is given in Lee's Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also give a map $\tilde M\to\mathbb S^2$ given by $(v,w)\mapsto\frac{v\times w}{\|v\times w\|}$, where $\times$ is the cross product. Since $\mathbb S^2$ is a covering space for $M\cong \mathbb RP^2$, there is a local diffeomorphism $\mathbb S^2\to M$ and so locally, the map I just gave ($\tilde M\to\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb{RP}^2\cong M$) and the map you gave ($\tilde M\to M$) would have the same expressions.